# Iterator of Container of Container

Tags: c++, iterator, collections

Based on [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/186457/507) I though I would pull together an iterator that iterated over a container of containers.

```
template<typename C>
class IteratorForContainerOfContainer
{
    public:
        using Container             = C;
        using ContainerContainer    = typename Container::value_type;
        using Contained             = typename ContainerContainer::value_type;

        using Level1Iter            = typename Container::iterator;
        using Level2Iter            = typename ContainerContainer::iterator;

        using iterator_category     = std::forward_iterator_tag;
        using value_type            = Contained;
        using difference_type       = std::size_t;
        using pointer               = value_type*;
        using reference             = value_type&;


        IteratorForContainerOfContainer(C& c)
            : outerLoop(std::begin(c))
            , outerEnd(std::end(c))
            , innerLoop(std::begin(*outerLoop))
            , innerEnd(std::end(*outerLoop))
        {
            nextValidPos();
        }
        IteratorForContainerOfContainer()
            : outerLoop()
            , outerEnd()
            , innerLoop()
            , innerEnd()
        {}


        IteratorForContainerOfContainer& operator++()
        {
            ++innerLoop;
            nextValidPos();
            return *this;
        }
        value_type& operator*()
        {
            return *innerLoop;
        }
        bool operator!=(IteratorForContainerOfContainer const& rhs) const
        {
            return outerLoop != rhs.outerLoop || innerLoop != rhs.innerLoop;
        }

        private:
            void nextValidPos()
            {
                while ((innerLoop == innerEnd) && (outerLoop != outerEnd)) {
                    ++outerLoop;
                    if (outerLoop != outerEnd) {
                        innerLoop = std::begin(*outerLoop);
                        innerEnd  = std::end(*outerLoop);
                    }
                }
                if (outerLoop == outerEnd) {
                    outerLoop   = Level1Iter();
                    outerEnd    = Level1Iter();
                    innerLoop   = Level2Iter();
                    innerEnd    = Level2Iter();
                }
            }
            Level1Iter          outerLoop;
            Level1Iter          outerEnd;
            Level2Iter          innerLoop;
            Level2Iter          innerEnd;
};
```

So an example of simple usage would be:

```
int main()
{
    using CC = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
    using It = IteratorForContainerOfContainer<CC>;

    CC   data = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

     for(It loop(data);loop != It(); ++loop) {
        std::cout << *loop << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

}
```

Comment: `nested_range` would be a great name for the iterator pair. Is there a reason you didn’t write range first? People could use range for loop then. I guess you had different usage in mind.

Comment: This operation is known as flattening ranges, IYAM

Answer (score 3):

If you try to get an `IteratorForContainerOfContainer` for an empty container, your constructor will run into Undefined Behavior when it tries to get the inner iterators because the outer container is empty, `outerLoop` will be the `end` iterator, and you can't dereference the `end` iterator.

You're using a default constructed object to double as an `end` iterator.  Consider adding in a static method to return one, `end(C &c)`, with appropriate changes to `nextValidPos`.

If you need to work with a `const` object, you won't be able to get one of these flattened iterators for it.

You don't define `operator++(int)`, so using `it++` won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

### Naming (a.k.a. "you probably don't care but..."):

- `ContainerContainer` `Container`. Aren't these backwards? (`ContainerContainer` is surely a container of containers...)
- `Level1Iter`, `ContainerContainer`, `OuterEnd`. That's 3 different prefixes for the same thing... maybe just use `Outer` and `Inner` everywhere.
- Use `Value` not `Contained`. The inner container is contained too, after all.

### Other:

- `using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;` oh reaaaally? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator (Not sure this is technically even an input iterator, since it's only got one increment operator).
- `std::begin(foo)` and `std::end(foo)` -> `using std::begin; begin(foo);`
- I think you're also going to run into problems with equality:

  - The value-initialized (default constructed) iterator isn't supposed to compare equal to an end iterator (it's a "singular value").
  - The equality operator shouldn't return true for two end iterators with different underlying containers (see the "multipass guarantee" section of the linked cppreference page).

---

EDIT:

You're quite right about being able to compare end iterators from different containers, and compare those end iterators with value-initialized iterators.

The relevant parts of the standard from n4659:

> 27.2.1 iterator.requirements.general p7
>
> Iterators can also have singular values that are not associated with any sequence. [...]
>   Results of most expressions are undefined for singular values; the
>   only exceptions are destroying an iterator that holds a singular value, the assignment of a non-singular
>   value to an iterator that holds a singular value, and, for iterators that satisfy the DefaultConstructible
>   requirements, using a value-initialized iterator as the source of a copy or move operation.

Doesn't explicitly say you can't add equality between value-initialized and non value-initialized iterators.

27.2.5 forward.iterators p2

> The domain of == for forward iterators is that of iterators over the
>   same underlying sequence. However, value-initialized iterators may be
>   compared and shall compare equal to other value-initialized iterators
>   of the same type. [ Note: Value-initialized iterators behave as if
>   they refer past the end of the same empty sequence. — end note ]

There's no "and" here but again, it doesn't say you can't add a comparison between value-initialized and end iterators. It also doesn't say you can't add `==` to compare iterators from different sequences.

So for a forward iterator it's fine.

But if you ever want to make this bidirectional, you need `--a == --b then a == b`, which won't be true with this implementation.

---

It seems easier to store a pointer to the outer container, and two iterators, combined with @1201ProgramAlarm's suggestion of the static end method:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iterator>

template<typename C>
class IteratorForContainerOfContainer
{
public:
    using OuterContainer = C;
    using InnerContainer = typename OuterContainer::value_type;
    using Value = typename InnerContainer::value_type;

    using OuterIter = typename OuterContainer::iterator;
    using InnerIter = typename InnerContainer::iterator;

    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = Value;
    using difference_type = std::size_t;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using reference = value_type&;

    explicit IteratorForContainerOfContainer(OuterContainer& c)
        : container(std::addressof(c))
    {
        begin();
    }

    IteratorForContainerOfContainer()
        : container(nullptr)
        , outer()
        , inner()
    {}

    IteratorForContainerOfContainer& operator++()
    {
        advance();

        return *this;
    }
    value_type& operator*()
    {
        using std::end;

        assert(container);
        assert(outer != end(*container));
        assert(inner != end(*outer));
        assert(inner != InnerIter());

        return *inner;
    }
    bool operator!=(IteratorForContainerOfContainer const& rhs) const
    {
        return container != rhs.container || outer != rhs.outer || inner != rhs.inner;
    }

    static IteratorForContainerOfContainer end(OuterContainer& c)
    {
        using std::end;

        auto result = IteratorForContainerOfContainer();
        result.container = std::addressof(c);
        result.outer = end(c);

        return result;
    }

private:

    void advanceUntilValid()
    {
        using std::begin;
        using std::end;

        assert(container);
        assert(outer != end(*container)); // advancing past the end is bad!

        while (inner == end(*outer))
        {
            std::advance(outer, 1);

            if (outer == end(*container))
            {
                inner = InnerIter();
                return;
            }

            inner = begin(*outer);
        }
    }

    void begin()
    {
        using std::begin;
        using std::end;

        assert(container);

        outer = begin(*container);

        if (outer == end(*container))
            return; // inner will never be valid (should be ok... I think... (singular values compare equal))

        inner = begin(*outer);

        advanceUntilValid();
    }

    void advance()
    {
        using std::begin;
        using std::end;

        assert(container);
        assert(outer != end(*container)); // advancing past the end is bad!
        assert(inner != end(*outer)); // should never be, because we always advance to the next valid value...

        std::advance(inner, 1);

        advanceUntilValid();
    }

    OuterContainer* container;
    OuterIter outer;
    InnerIter inner;
};

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using CC = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
    using It = IteratorForContainerOfContainer<CC>;

    CC data = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };

    for (It loop(data); loop != It::end(data); ++loop) {
        std::cout << *loop << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I care a lot about naming.

Comment: Its a forward iterator (you can use it do multi passes over the container). **BUT** it definitely does not have all the requirements for an iterator I was waiting for that to be called out.

Comment: There is no requirement that end iterators from different containers need to be not equivalent. `Equality and inequality comparison is defined over all iterators for the same underlying sequence and the value initialized-iterators`.

Comment: ForwardIterator iterators must be default constructable. Since these have no value associated and are comparable with iterators from a sequence this means they are end iterators.

Comment: @MartinYork You might be right, I'm not sure... but this bit says: `A value-initialized ForwardIterator behaves like the past-the-end iterator of **some unspecified empty container**` which implies you can't compare it with an iterator from an actual container. I read the sentence you've quoted as meaning that value-initialized iterators have equality with other value-initialized iterators, not necessarily with iterators that are associated with an actual container. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190112/comparing-default-constructed-iterators-with-operator.

Comment: Thats an incorrect logical leap. Especially since it explicitly says its valid for `for the same underlying sequence **AND** the value initialized-iterators` It explicitly says you can compare an iterator against a value initialized iterator. I should also note this is how `std::istream_iterator` works so is a concept that is used by iterators in the standard. If you read it your way what is the **AND** referring to?

Comment: If you follow your own link and read the second answer (the correct one) https://stackoverflow.com/a/24145199/14065 you will see the correct quote from the standard.

Comment: I think that "and" is just a rather ambiguous rewording of the standard in cppreference. I read it as: "== must be defined between iterators of the same underlying sequence. == must be defined between value-initialized iterators of the same type."

It's certainly not a requirement, because `std::vector<int>().end() == std::vector<int>::iterator()` doesn't work.

Comment: @ user673679: I would disagree. That seems to work as I would expect. https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler  https://www.jdoodle.com/a/lW2 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/049a6e8cdea3db5c https://ideone.com/UMIlOc https://www.codechef.com/ide

Comment: And on MSVC, that same code is `Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: vector iterators incompatible`.

Comment: @MartinYork You are right though. The standard doesn't explicitly forbid this. I'd just argue that it's a bad idea. I've edited the answer to clarify a bit.

Comment: But this is straying way of course. This is not the point i am making. The standard already has iterators that mark the end where all ends are the same. So using the same pattern here should not be surprising (or that autragious or unexpected). Have a look at std::istream_iterator where this pattern is used.

Comment: @user6736679: I bet it only does that it dubug mode. Where extra code is explicitly added to add to do the test. In release mode it will also work as expected I bet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72778/discussion-between-user673679-and-martin-york).

Comment: I would argue that it is a good idea as we are echoing a standard pattern that is used in the standard library.

Comment: Well, it's your code, so have at it. :p